# Multiple XMLHttpRequests At Once

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I am building a php uploader and I have this javascript that is rendered for each file selected for upload.

```
        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append("file1", file);

        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
        ajax.open("POST", "fileUploader.php");

        startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
        ajax.send(formdata);
```

I want to be able to update a different progressbar for each request; however, but I cannot figure out how to do this.

This is my progresshandler function

```
function progressHandler(event) {
document.getElementById("upProgress").value = event.loaded/event.total * 100;
}
```

How do I dynamically select the progress bar instead of always selected "upProgress" bar?

NEW CODE:

```
var pgb = function(div, progBar) {
            this.div = div;
            this.progBar = progBar;

            var _this = this;

            this.progressHandler = function(event) {
                _this.progBar.value = event.loaded/event.total * 100;
            }
            this.completeHandler = function(event) {
                _this.div.innerHTML += "...done";

                console.log(_this.progBar);
            }
        }
```

And then for each file the following is done.

```
var l_pbg = new pgb(document.getElementById('div_'+index), document.getElementById('up_'+index));

            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
            ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", l_pbg.progressHandler, false);
            ajax.addEventListener("load", l_pbg.completeHandler, false);
            ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
            ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
            ajax.open("POST", "fileUploader.php");

            startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
            ajax.send(formdata);
```

The problem now is that only the last file to be uploaded has its progressbar updated; however both files do get uploaded.  I can see that the progressHandler is being called the all however as I had it print in the console, so does only the first update visually?:

[image: Console]

[image: Visual]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a class that references a DOM element, and has a progressHandler method:

```
var Pgb =  function(elem) {
    this.elem = elem;

    var _this = this;
    this.progressHandler = function(event) {
        _this.elem.value = event.loaded/event.total * 100;
    }
}
```

Then create an instance of this class for each progress bar:

```
var pgb1 = new Pgb(document.getElementById("upProgress1"));
var pgb2 = new Pgb(document.getElementById("upProgress2"));
```

Then pass the method as the handler for each as the ajax event listener:

```
ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", pgb1.progressHandler, false);
ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", pgb2.progressHandler, false);
```

Working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/rrun9ftz/

Comment: I tired what you said but I encountered another problem where they don't both update visually?  Why is this?  You can see that any visual changes that occur with regards to the first post are ignored as not even the "...done" is displayed.

Comment: I cannot see a problem with your code. But maybe this will help: https://jsfiddle.net/rrun9ftz/    I've created an example. When you click "upload" it adds a progress bar to the page, and then starts a simulated upload process that uses the progress handler to update the progress bar. You can click multiple times and watch multiple bars being updated independently.

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with the XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so. When you added `console.log(_this.progBar);` to `progressHandler`, you could see it being called for each progress bar? And you could see the value being updated? But visually, nothing changed?

Comment: This is correct, look at the my post.  You can see in the console that up_0 and up_1 are being updated, simply not the progressbars

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by refinding the progress by via document.getElementById(_this.progBar.id) and then setting the value.